# Configuring Network with OpenVPN and GUFW for Secure Only Thought VPN Traffic. Configuring Self-made Kill Switch on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, autostart

Hi guys I was searching for a basic way to config my connections through a VPN without leaking my IP.

I have some questions

1. What's the best VPN manager for Kubuntu / Ubuntu?
2. Easy for beginner friendly way to block all connections that are not running through a VPN
3. How to force autostart of VPN in Ubuntu

In windows the a function similar to this is called kill switch and whenever the vpn is reconnecting or down the firewall blocks all access to internet.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a good tutorial on how to set up a kill switch with ufw here: https://gist.github.com/Necklaces/18b68e80bf929ef99312b2d90d0cded2

Answer (score 0):

If the best is openvpn

You need to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn 

sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
```

If you have any problems with the openvpn as I had at the beginning you can run the following command to know what's happening

```
grep VPN /var/log/syslog
```

Then you can add a openvpn configuration from the Network Manager. It's also possible to set autoconnect all from the Network Manager.

However I'm still looking to a Firewall solution for dropouts (Kill Switch)

And I'm not sure if IPv6 configuration should be changed...